# Simplify horrible R code to adjust row means

Tags: r, loops, performance

I know this code can be made much shorter and more efficient using R's powerful vector handling capabilities. I just cannot figure out how at the moment...

The basic task is to adjust cells within each row so that the row total is forced to match a predefined number, determined by another data frame. That way the total population of each area is forced to a certain value (each row represents an area), while the ratios between the cells moving from one column to the next remains the same.

Ugly way of doing it (first loop is just to create an example data frame; sure that could be done better and all; I just can't stop using loops!):

```
con1 <- array(dim=c(5,3))

set.seed(1066)
for(i in 1:ncol(con1)){
con1[,i] <- round(rnorm(n=5,mean=10,sd=3))}
con1 <- data.frame(con1)
con2 <- data.frame(array(c(8:13, 9:14, 10:15), dim=c(5,3)))

apply(con1,1, sum)
apply(con2,1, sum) # different row totals

con1.adj <- con1
for ( i in 1:nrow(con1)){
  con1.adj[i,1] <- con1[i,1] * ( sum(con2[i,]) / sum(con1[i,]) )
  con1.adj[i,2] <- con1[i,2] * ( sum(con2[i,]) / sum(con1[i,]) )
  con1.adj[i,3] <- con1[i,3] * ( sum(con2[i,]) / sum(con1[i,]) )
}
con1.adj <- data.frame(con1.adj)
apply(con1.adj,1, sum) # same row totals
```

(context: Dug up this code up from someone else's work and used merrily for a while. It looks awful to me now that I've inched a little way up the steep R learning curve. Also want the code to be re-used by others. Really enjoying the language, and will enjoy it even more if I can find a more beautiful way of doing this)

Comment: `apply(con1,1, sum)` and similar lines have no real value in your code. You just calculate the sum and do not store it anywhere!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I already know that! Its for the benefit of humans who perform the above steps on their home computers. It's not included in the code I'm using, that would make it even uglier (if that were possible :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this one-liner should do the job:

```
con1.adj <- con1 * rowSums(con2) / rowSums(con1)
```

Comment: maybe add starting data `con1 <- data.frame( array( round( rnorm( 15 , 10 , 3 ) ) , dim = c( 5 , 3 ) ) ) ; con2 <- data.frame( array( c(8:13, 9:14, 10:15 ) , dim=c(5,3) ) )` too?  :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Why? Its the first 7 lines in the question, so no need to repeat here in the answer.

Comment: EDi, that's just the ticket: multiplied through the script you've saved ~100 lines code so many many thanks. You've confirmed my love of R! (Cursing myself for not figuring that out myself.) Will stick to the philosophy that you learn best by making mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion to generate your `con1` in a slightly better way

```
rgen <- function(X,mean=10,sd=3){
  round(rnorm(n=length(X),mean=mean,sd=sd))
}

con1 <- data.frame(apply(con1,2,rgen))
```

Note that the size of your random vector will match your `array` dimension and you can pass different `mean` and `sd` dynamically e.g. `apply(con1,2,rgen,5,2)` which will generate `rnorm` with `mean=5` and `sd=2`

Comment: Many thanks for this useful hint iTech: only just realized it was a comment about generating the test data and not an attempted answer. Very neat. Now I need zero loops wahey!